# R: getting data (instead of plot) back from sm.density.compare

Tags: r, statistics, density-plot, raw-data

I'm doing a density compare in R using the sm package (sm.density.compare). Is there anyway I can get a mathematical description of the graph or at least a table with number of points rather than a plot back? I would like to plot the resulting graphs in a different application, but need the data to do so.

Thanks a lot for the help,
culicidae

Comment: Yes, set your call to be equal to a variable: z<-sm.density.compare(y,g,model="equal") then you can get it all out by seeing what is in z

Comment: You're a champion! Thanks a lot!
Do you by any chance also know how to specify the number of points I want for that graph? Default seems to be 50... more would be nice for a smother graph.