# use sm.density.compare to plot density functions, draw lines for each mode and get the mode values back

Tags: r, statistics, density-plot

I have got dive depth data for seabirds over several trips and I would like to find the modes for each trip, plot the density functions and a line corresponding to the modes. So far, here's the code I have been using:

```
maxdepths<-read.csv("maximum_depths.csv", header=T)
maxdepths_ind21<-maxdepths[maxdepths$bird=="21",]
# create value labels 
trip.f <- factor(maxdepths_ind21$trip, levels= c(21.1,21.2,21.3,21.4,21.5,21.6,21.7,21.8),
                labels = c("Trip1", "Trip2", "Trip3", "Trip4", "Trip5", "Trip6", "Trip7", "Trip8")) 

# plot densities 
z<-sm.density.compare(maxdepths_ind21$maxdep, maxdepths_ind21$trip,model="equal") 

sm.density.compare(maxdepths_ind21$maxdep, maxdepths_ind21$trip, xlab="Maximum depth (m)", xlim=c(0, 90), axes=F)
title(main="Maximum dive depth by trip, individu 21")
axis(side = 1, at = c(0,5,10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90))
axis(side = 2, at = c(0,0.01,0.02,0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 1))

# add legend via mouse click
colfill<-c(2:(2+length(levels(trip.f)))) 
legend(locator(1), levels(trip.f), fill=colfill)
```

The result looks good, ie I've got one curve per trip with different colours/line types per trip.

I now would like to draw lines for each trip when the density functions are maximized, as well as find those values. I am aware of this thread
[R: getting data (instead of plot) back from sm.density.compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252058/r-getting-data-instead-of-plot-back-from-sm-density-compare) 
and I have tried assigning the result of sm.density.compare to an object and then calling it, like so:

```
z<-sm.density.compare(maxdepths_ind21$maxdep, maxdepths_ind21$trip,model="equal") 
z
```

I was looking for the values of the modes within this output but I got confused by all the values that are returned. 
Any help would be much appreciated!
TIA